# UDP send test fails on amazon ec2 - all outgoing traffic enabled

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, udp

I'm running an ubuntu 14.04 instance on amazon ec2- I can't seem to send any udp packets from my instance to my local machine.

Running the followings commands:
On amazon ec2 instance:

echo "test" | netcat -vu m.y.i.p 5500

> Connection to m.y.i.p 5500 port [udp/*] succeeded!

On my local machine:

netcat -luv 5500

> Listening on [0.0.0.0] (family 0, port 5500)

So we successfully make a connection, but I never receive the test packet on my local machine.

Is there anything else I might need to configure with my instance for this to work?

Answer (score 1):

A UDP transmission does not have a connection (as does TCP) so the message "Connection to m.y.i.p 5500 port [udp/*] succeeded!" doesn't really tell you much about the true success of the transmission of a packet from A to B. It might have never even left the originating machine (due to some firewall rule).

In my experience most common UDP problems are firewall blocks at the incoming machine so you certainly need to check on any firewall rules that might be blocking UDP incoming on port 5500.

If that looks ok, then the easiest way to debug is to use a packet sniffer (tcpdump, wireshark or similar). First confirm that a UDP packet is leaving your source machine, then try to see it incoming on the target machine.

```
tcpdump host m.y.i.p
```

Comment: Thanks, Hankster.  Seems that the problem is that my router is blocking the packet on non-essential ports.  So now I'm thinking that I need to look into ["UDP hole punching"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UDP_hole_punching) to make my application work.

Comment: For sure, a router doing NAT with its own firewall rules is going to get in the way. But the fix may be simple (or not). First try to DMZ your machine and see if that works. Next, your router might have some kind of "static route" that will take packets directly from the EC2 address to your target. Finally, there might be some protocol table where you can add the necessary routes and ports. Glad you found the source of the block.